# Adding MediaClips in to MediaComposition eats too much RAM

Tags: uwp

I was trying to generate a video from the screenshots of an UI using `MediaComposition` and `MediaClips`. Basically I used a `DispatcherTimer` with interval set to 50 millisecond and handled the `Tick` event like this:

```
private async void Tm_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap rendertargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await rendertargetBitmap.RenderAsync(myGrid);
    var bfr = await rendertargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    CanvasRenderTarget rendertarget = null;
    using (CanvasBitmap canvas = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), bfr, rendertargetBitmap.PixelWidth, rendertargetBitmap.PixelHeight, Windows.Graphics.DirectX.DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized))
    {
        rendertarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), canvas.SizeInPixels.Width, canvas.SizeInPixels.Height, 96);
        using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = rendertarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Black);
            ds.DrawImage(canvas);
        }
    }
    MediaClip m = MediaClip.CreateFromSurface(rendertarget, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000/60));
    MediaCompositions[MediaCompositionNumber].Clips.Add(m);
}
```

and to stop this recording , I used a `button's click event like this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tm.Stop();
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Video" + identifier + ".mp4", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    if (file is null)
        return;

    await mediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync(file, MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise, MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD1080p));
    mediaComposition.Clips.Clear();
}
```

Most of the time , this code works fine. But when the UI is large, like occupying the whole screen, the `CanvasRenderTarget rendertarget` has to hold a lot more data. The result is, the RAM consumption goes extremely high.

Look at memory consumtion of the application *Win2DVideoRenderingTest* at the top:
[image: memory consumtion]

I myself don't have any problem with that huge memory consumtion, but the problem is that, the whole operating system becomes almost unresponsive or very laggy. After surpassing 1.5-1.6 GB Memory, sometimes the consumtions suddenly reduces to 150 MB or such (why?) , but the operating system is still becoming more unresponsive. I even have to restart my desktop as I can't do anything then.

The final video size is only 21.7 MB. May be the raw, uncompressed bitmap data is taking this much memory. But my wit says that there should be some way, may be compressing the bitmap data, or may be somehow offloading these data to Disk?

Is there any way to reduce the memory consumption?

Comment: this might help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/improve-garbage-collection-performance

Comment: nah, I tried to use the Memory Analyzer, it itself start behaving abnormally

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the UI, it may be more efficient to draw the UI in realtime onto the mediaframes directly using Win2D, with no XAML interplay. Taking 20 full frame bitmaps in memory per second is... well, there's not much you can do to reduce memory consumption with that technique. You're storing a massive amount of bitmaps in-memory. If you really need XAML (which is super slow anyway to render from), trying rendering to a StorageFile and then creating MediaClip from StorageFile? No guarantee it won't still all load into memory however.